# apply surface friction in box2d

Tags: cocos2d-x, game-physics, box2d

I start to try clone this game with box2d/cocos2d-x
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.miniclip.carrom&hl=en&gl=US
and I have multi problem and need your help.
first: how I can simulate surface friction?
I try to use SetLinearDamping & SetAngularDamping but the result is not very interesting.

Answer (score 0):

i use b2FrictionJoint and solve it.box2d use b2FrictionJoint for top-down friction. The joint provides 2D translational friction and angular friction